# How to use a variable between two thread groups

Tags: jmeter

I have two thread groups

1. Creation of customer
2. Creation of account

From first thread group I'm capturing a variable called customerId.

How can I use that variable in second thread group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't share a variable, you **can** convert variable to JMeter property using [__setProperty](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)

```
${__setProperty(propertyName, ${variableName})}
```

> The setProperty function sets the value of a JMeter property.

And use in second thread group use [__property](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property)

```
 ${__property(propertyName)}
```

You can convert it back to JMeter variable:

```
 ${__property(propertyName, newVariableName)}
```

> ${__property(user.dir,UDIR)} - return value of user.dir and save in UDIR